# Insert data from column as average in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, average, sql-insert

I have a table named `feedback` which has columns `mechEmail` (foreign key) and `rate` in it.

I have another table named `mechanical` which has columns `email` (primary key) and `avgrate`.

I want to insert the average rate from the `feedback` table into the `mechanical` table where `mechEmail` matches `email`.

Here's the code that I used, but it only selects - but does not insert:

```
SELECT 
    mechanical.email, 
    COALESCE(AVG(feedback.rate), 0) AS rate
FROM 
    mechanical
LEFT JOIN 
    feedback ON feedback.mechEmail = mechanical.email
GROUP BY 
    mechanical.email;
```

Comment: You put this inside a INSERT INTO function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't want an Insert statement but an UPDATE statement as you already have email in mechanical table -

```
UPDATE mechanical M
  JOIN (SELECT mechEmail, AVG(rate) rate
          FROM feedback
         GROUP BY mechEmail) F ON F.mechEmail = M.email
   SET M.avgrate = F.rate;
```

Comment: this code worked well but it showed avg rate as 5 not 4.3 as expected i have rate of(5,5,3)

Comment: For that, You need to show your sample data and expected result.

Comment: sample data are (5,5,3)  ,,, expected result is 4.333,,,,shown result is 5

Comment: (5,5,3)  is in feedback table or in mechanical table?

Comment: in the feedback table

Comment: i noticed that the first rating only what shows on the mechanical table

Comment: @YahiaMohamed, Please try the edited query...

Comment: @YahiaMohamed, Always welcome.